# Redirecting output efficiently in C

Tags: c, bash, io

I was wondering which one of these two prompt lines is better performance-wise:

- `./function input > output.txt`
- `./function input output.txt`

Now, some context, my function only uses `fprintf` for printing the output, example:

```
fprintf(output," whatever");
```

So, which one of the alternatives mentioned above will behave better performance-wise? Redirecting the stdout or directly printing in the file?

Comment: If you really care, you should measure it yourself (but I expect there will be no difference).

Comment: The difference – if any at all – is likely absolutely negligible, probably not even measurable.

Comment: Yes, I know that I should check that. But I'd like some insight, in a deep level, of which one is a good habit to keep, not only in this example :).

Comment: As melpomene said, do your own benchmark. Now, as you're the programmer you _really should_ make sure your program handles both cases (outputs to `stdout` if no `-o output.txt` option is given).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Yup. I read argc and declare the variables. Something among the lines: 
    if(argc==2) output=argv[2];
    else output=stdout;

Comment: you'll need to `fopen` argv[1]  (not 2) and check for failure

Comment: I would ask what your performance requirements are and what your expected inputs are? Until that is defined, there's no way to determine optimal performance.

Comment: @WilliamMorris Yes, William, my code does work. Im just wondering if printing directly in the file is better than redirecting the output.

Comment: It can make no difference. In both cases, you have an open FILE structure. The only difference is that the shell did an `fopen`, or the equivalent, for you in the redirection case and that you called `fopen` directly in the other. You end up with a FILE either way.  Once the file is open, there can be no performace difference.

Comment: @cowboydan I don't strictly have any requirements, but if there is a faster solution, I would gladly take it. I read a binary file and I parse its contents bit-wise, then print it in a legible way on the .txt. Again, I'm looking for a general answer, not a specific one on my aplication. Even a "depends" would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two approaches is only which process opens the file for writing and closes it. So there is no performance difference while running your program. The fact that five (stdin, stdout, stderr, "input" and "output.txt") file descriptors are open instead of only four (when writing the output to stdout) makes no difference.

Of course for your program to behave in exactly the same way whether it writes to stdout or to a file, it must write to the file also line-buffered (as is does per default when writing to stdout).

If you do not call `setvbuf()` on the file struct you got from `fopen()` like this `setvbuf(stream, (char *) NULL, _IOLBF, 0);` (took this from the manpage of `setvbuf()`)  your program will use block buffering and in most cases this will be faster than the redirect to stdout.

So if your program is allowed to use block buffering for its output, the `./function input output.txt` will be faster. (But the comments about your questions are valid: Do measure the real performance!)